# Return newly generated cell value in MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I run this code, it generates a sequential number.

I want to display the new sequential number in a MsgBox, but it prints the older sequential number.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

    Dim reponse As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim REVISIONRNCAUTO As Workbook
    Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim cell_value As String
    Set REVISIONRNCAUTO = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Sheet2 = REVISIONCRNAUTO.Worksheets(2)

    cell_value = Sheet2.Cells(4, "A").Value & Sheet2.Cells(4, "B").Value

    If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox4.Value = True And CheckBox7.Value = True And CheckBox2.Value = False And CheckBox3.Value = False _
       And CheckBox6.Value = False And CheckBox5.Value = False And CheckBox8.Value = False And CheckBox9.Value = False And CheckBox10.Value = False And CheckBox11.Value = False And CheckBox12.Value = False _
       And CheckBox13.Value = False And CheckBox14.Value = False And CheckBox15.Value = False Then

        Sheet2.Activate

        reponse = MsgBox("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir générer ce RNC?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Enregistrement RNC")
        If reponse = vbYes Then

            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Select
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4:E4").Select
            Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Select
            ActiveCell.Value = "=b5+1"

            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A4").Select
            Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
            ActiveCell.Value = "E"

        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
     End If

     MsgBox ("Le nouveau RNC enregistré est le : " & cell_value)
```

Comment: You arent changing the value of `cell_value` after you set it.. They are not linked forever. You have to set it again. Put the `cell_value=` line right before the else in addition to where it currently is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't changing the value of `cell_value` after you set it.

They are not linked forever like an Excel formula. You have to set it again once you change the cells that it is based on.

Put the `cell_value =` line right before the `Else` in addition to where it currently is.